# Avoiding escape sequence processing in ActionScript?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, text

I need to mimic C# functionality of the @ symbol when it precedes a string.

@"C:\A\File\Path" for example

What is the best way to do this?  Also there are some sites that will escape larger strings for you so that they survive the processing but I could not find one for Actionscript.

Help?

Answer (score 2):

No, unfortunately there is no support for verbatim string literals in actionscript. You are going to have to escape them manually. Even calling string.replace("\", "\\") doesn't work.